# TSQL Join, Query Processing order and storage

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, query-optimization

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Transactions
(
    actid INT NOT NULL, --Account ID
    tranid INT NOT NULL,  -- Transaction ID
    val MONEY NOT NULL, --- Transaction value

    CONSTRAINT PK_Transactions PRIMARY KEY(actid, tranid)
);
```

The following inefficient query tries to determine the running balance after each transaction

```
SELECT 
    T1.actid, T1.tranid, T1.val,
    SUM(T2.val) AS balance
FROM 
    dbo.Transactions AS T1
JOIN 
    dbo.Transactions AS T2 ON T2.actid = T1.actid
                           AND T2.tranid <= T1.tranid
GROUP BY 
    T1.actid, T1.tranid, T1.val;
```

I am not sure how the join is processed in query. Is the join treated as a subquery where for each group (`T1.actid, T1.tranid, T1.val`) the join statement is executed? Does that mean if there 10K Transactions , 10K joined data sets are created by this query?

Answer (score 0):

Execute your query in SSMS. Then highlight it and press **Ctrl + L** to view the Execution Plan. This will show you how SQL Server plans to execute the query and sometimes suggest indexes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It means you will have exactly number of rows the join satisfy

Each row in T1 is processed and brings in rows from T2 that satisfies the join conditions.

The join can be process as loop, hash, or merge.  Typically the optimizer ill use hash.

The best think to do is just run it.  The output should tell a story.

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY way to know is by 'studying' the query plan.

FYI: it seems to me your query is equivalent to

```
SELECT 
    T1.actid, T1.tranid, T1.val,
    balance = (SELECT SUM(T2.val)
                 FROM dbo.Transactions
                WHERE T2.actid = T1.actid
                  AND T2.tranid <= T1.tranid)
FROM 
    dbo.Transactions AS T1
```

To be honest, I prefer 'this' version because it looks more readable to me; I'm also expecting this version to be slightly 'leaner' as there is less need for sorting, but only actual testing will tell. It's sometimes surprising to see what the optimizer does behind the scenes! Again, the query plan will show.

Therefore, run both queries and compare the resulting query plans, those should give you an idea about their relative cost. Now, keep in mind that "cost" isn't always directly correlated to "time"; so you might want to check which one runs faster too on your hardware and under 'typical load'; also keep in mind that e.g. caching may have an effect here!